# Change order of coc nvim diagnostics to prioritize typescript over eslint?

Tags: eslint, coc.nvim

I use coc-eslint and coc-tsserver but find it frustrating that eslint's errors always appear before tsserver's

For instance this is a common error when I haven't imported `Foo` yet.

```
[eslint @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call] [E] Unsafe construction of an any
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-call
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
[tsserver 2304] [E] Cannot find name 'Foo'.
```

Is there a way to configure change the priority of coc plugins, or configure coc-eslint to emit all diagnostics as warnings instead of errors?